# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un código basado en el tamaño de la pantalla?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, web, mediaqueries

hasta ahora estaba intentando poner un código específico para los ordenadores e intentando ponerle otro a los móviles en función del tamaño de la pantalla y he probado con los media query:

```html
/* Common general styles go here */
/* Mobiles in Potrait mode */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
<p>Hey!</p>
}
 
/* Mobiles in landscape mode */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px)
and (max-width : 480px) {
<p>Hey!</p>
}
 
/* Tablets */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 1024px) {
<p>Hey!</p>
}
 
/* Desktops and laptops computers */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
<p>Hey PC!</p>
}
```

No me funcionan las media query. Eso o las he implementado mal (he probado tanto en el archivo .css como a ponerlo directamente en un archivo .php).

¿Sabéis dónde está el error?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Está mal la estructura de los archivos, el CSS con los estilos y los media query van por un lado y el html por otro.

Dentro de cada media query van los estilos que querés que adopten los elementos.

```css
/* Common general styles go here */
/* Mobiles in Potrait mode */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}
 
/* Mobiles in landscape mode */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px)
and (max-width : 480px) {
  p {
    color: blue;
  }
}
 
/* Tablets */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 1024px) {
  p {
    color: green;
  }
}
 
/* Desktops and laptops computers */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
  p {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Hey PC!</p>
```

Comment: Gracias por la información. ¿Y cómo podría hacer para implementar un código dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla? Más o menos como lo tenía en el texto de la pregunta.

Comment: A ver si comprendo, vos querés que muestre un texto u otro dependiendo de la resolución del navegador?

Comment: Sí (un script en realidad).

Comment: Tenés dos opciones, si sólo va a mostrar/ocultar un texto, podés hacerlo con css, y jugar con el `display: block|none;` para mostrar u ocultar un nodo. Ahora si bien querés que se ejecuten funciones y haga más cosas dependiendo de la resolución deberías usar javascript pero sólo si no se puede hacer con CSS. ¿Qué es lo que pretendés hacer? Así puedo darte una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Quiero poner un anuncio de adsense (va mediante scripts) dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla para que sea mejor la experiencia de usuario.